# Parsing image of a point cloud with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, feature-extraction

I have a [point cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0UBk.jpg) 
and would like to extract the coordinates of the points from it.

The following python opencv (3.2.0-dev) script is used for the extraction.

```
image = cv2.imread(PIC_FILE)
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_,image_thres = cv2.threshold(image_gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image_thres = 255 - image_thres
pixelpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(image_thres))
```

But the problem is that for a point, which are containing multiple pixels in the picture, I get multiple point coordinates.

Currently the value `len(pixelpoints)` is about 9000, which seems to be much more than we can see in the picture.

How can I collapse these multiple pixels into one single coordinate, which - for example - is the center of a point?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you will not be able to achieve the wished for results with the image you provided. At least, not with high precision. Given the first pixel points result in something like:

`[ 13 118][ 13 125][ 13 126][ 13 127][ 13 131][ 13 132][ 13 133][ 14 117][ 14 118][ 14 119][ 14 123][ 14 124][ 14 125][ 14 126][ 14 127][ 14 131][ 14 132][ 14 133]`

You could of course group these according to one of their axes. You could also set a maximum number of pixelpoints to be related to a single dot. However, your image also includes multiple areas in which the dots are placed all together, overlapping, so you could never know for sure how many dots there are in these areas. Furthermore, the dots are not similar in shape, some are 3 pixels wide, others just 2, etc. And they keep rotating.

Overall.. you might be able to finetune your guess, but you won't get a perfect match with the current image.

PS: I am not as familiar with bumpy though.. maybe it has some functions to create a better estimation, but still these algorithms are likely to achieve an educated guess at best with the provided image.